# dynamic stack structures with pointers

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I'm building a dynamic stack that requires a structure with a pointer to an array.

```
class studentstack
{

  private:
          struct StackNode
          {
                  int ID;
                  string Name;
                  string Address;
                  StackNode * next; // pointer to the next node
                  double * scores; // pointer to the arry of scores
          };
```

when in my main file im trying to fill the array with doubles then pass it to a function and when I do nothing seems to pass right. what is the correct way of doing this?

```
int main()
{
    studentstack s;

    string name;
    int id;
    string address;
    double score;




    for(int x =0; x<20; x++)
    {
        cout << "\nNew Student Name: ";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "\nID: ";
        cin >> id;

        cout << "\nAddress: ";
        cin >> address;

        double scoresArr[10];

        for(int z=0; z<10; z++)
        {
                cout << "\nStudent Score " << z+1 << ": ";
                cin >> score;
                scoresArr[z] = score;
        }

        s.push(name, id, address, scoresArr);
```

push:

```
void studentstack::push(string name, int id, string address, double scoresArr)
{
     StackNode *newStudent; // To point to the new Student

     newStudent = new StackNode;
     newStudent-> ID = id;
     newStudent-> Name = name;
     newStudent-> Address = address;
     newStudent-> scores = scoresArr;

     // If there are no nodes in the stack
     if (isEmpty())
     {
        top = newStudent;
        newStudent->next= NULL;
     }
     else // or add before top
     {
          newStudent->next = top;
          top = newStudent;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you put your `push` code?

Comment: the `push` code you've given will not compile with the call shown. it won't even compile on its own. please **copy and paste** real code, don't type it in by hand.

Comment: The `double scoresArr` parameter should be a pointer. Aren't you getting any compile errors?

Answer (score 0):

The technical problem is in the code you haven't showed yet (as I'm writing this), namely the `push` code.

However, there is a simple solution that will work no matter how your `push` screws up things.

Namely, use a `std::vector` instead of a dynamically allocated raw array.

Or, simply use a fixed size raw array in each node.

For that matter, a `std::list` would be better than a DIY linked list, but presumably the whole point of this exercise is to gain some familiarity with linked list structures. Using a `std::vector` for the array in each node, won't interfere with that goal. But keep in mind that in modern C++ creating a linked list yourself is very rarely a good solution, whatever the problem is – instead, use standard library container classes, and/or container classes from third party libraries.

Comment: if it was up to me I would use the stl library but the teacher wants us to create our own list... and sorry about the code it's a little mixed up I've been changing between arrays and pointers and double pointers. considering this is just going into a portfolio and I have already writing a linked list I will probably just change to a stl list anyway.